# Can you offer me English translators, dictionaries to use in my PC?

Tags: discussion

I seek dictionary or translator can be used offline

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use of:

> [Longman Exam Coach (PC)](https://vqminhhoctienganh.blogspot.com/2017/10/longman-exams-coach-dictionary-cd-rom.html)
>
> [Merriam-Webster (iOS/Android)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/apps)